# Sending a JSON formatted job application to a REST API via POST: getting an SSL exception

Tags: java, json, rest, ssl

**Context:**

I want to submit a job application to a company, the instructions for doing so are posted here ("Apply via our REST API"):
https://3sidedcube.com/contact/join-us

**What I have done:**

I have wrote a simple app to send the application, it uses "Android Asynchronous HTTP Client" library to do most of the legwork: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

This is the code for the app:

MainActivity:

```
package jobsrc;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.jobapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.loopj.android.http.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendRequest();
            }
        });     
    }

    private void sendRequest() {
        final String TAG = "jobApp";
        Log.i(TAG, "Sending post..");   

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
//      //fill params here..
        try {
            params.put("name", "TEST");     
            params.put("email", "TEST");
            params.put("message", "TEST");
            params.put("cv-link", "TEST");
            params.put("github-profile", "TEST");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        StringEntity se = null;
        try{
            se = new StringEntity(params.toString());
        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){

        }

        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

        //DEBUG
        //requestbin test: ("http://requestb.in/18jj7lk1?inspect" to see result)
        //client.post(null, "http://requestb.in/18jj7lk1", se, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

        //submission URL: transmission fails with error: 
        //  "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <3sidedcube.com> != <*.cubeapis.com> OR <*.cubeapis.com> OR <cubeapis.com>"
        client.post(null, "https://3sidedcube.com/api/jobs", se, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    JSONArray response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Success: array");
                Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Success: object");
                Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    String responseString) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Success: string");
                Log.i(TAG, responseString);
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseString);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    Throwable throwable, JSONArray errorResponse) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                    Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
            }

        });

    }
}
```

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Send.." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The problem:**

When I run my code, I get an onFailure response, which is receiving an SSL exception, debug reveals the exception as:

```
"javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <3sidedcube.com> != <*.cubeapis.com> OR <*.cubeapis.com> OR <cubeapis.com>"
```

**What I need to know:**

Is this my fault, or theirs? I am not an expert on this sort of thing, so it's very possible I'm doing something silly!

I tested my POST request using RequestBin ("http://requestb.in/18jj7lk1?inspect") and it seemed to ECHO correctly and accurately, so I feel like it may be an issue on their side?

Anyway, if it is my fault, I'll want to correct what I'm doing, if it is their fault, I'll send them an email and explain the issue to them.

Let me know what you think, and Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://www.3sidedcube.com indeed provides a cert with `CN=*.cubeapis.com`. Either you can disable the host name verification by overwriting the SSL context or ask the service provider for the correct host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either 3sidedcube.com needs to fix their certificate with accurate domain(CN) or you need to disable host name validation. You can use the code given below to bypass the validation.

```
  ....
  KeyStore trustStore=KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
  trustStore.load(null,null);
  SSLSocketFactory socketFactory=new InsecureSSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
  socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
  client.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
  client.post(null, "https://3sidedcube.com/api/jobs", se, "application/json", new         JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
  .....
```

Comment: Thankyou, this resolved the SSL issue. Had some minor difficulty with the SSLSocketFactory import as it's in two namespaces, but worked fine when i fixed that. (if anyone is the same issue, make sure you import the Apache version)

Unfortunately i now get a 404 when I send my request to "https://3sidedcube.com/api/jobs", so I'm guessing it's their setup that is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers at 3 Sided Cube. Thanks for spotting our deliberate mistake with the API ;-)

If you try your request now at https://3sidedcube.com/api/job you should get a more helpful response.

Good Luck!

Comment: Awesome, my code worked first time :) thanks for getting back to me!